# How can I set the root domain as CNAME record with cloudfront?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-cloudfront

I would like to point my root domain (`abc.example`) into cloudfront CNAME record (`xxx.cloudfront.net`). However, CNAME with @ as Host is not allowed at GoDaddy.

[image: godaddy Setting]

I wish `https://abc.example` is able to point to `xxx.cloudfront.net`.

How can I make the change?

Comment: "CNAME with @ as Host is not allowed at GoDaddy. "  It is *nowhere* allowed since, by design of the DNS a CNAME record can not coexist with other records, and at apex (root of the zone) you already have NS and SOA records

Comment: Godaddy provides URL redirection and you csan configure to redirect example.com to www.example.com because you can create a CNAME for www.example.com , only problem is if someone accesses https://example.com because godaddy does't use cert for url redirection.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can redirect your own custom domain name to Amazon CloudFront but **you will need to use Amazon Route 53** instead of a third-party DNS service.

From [Routing Traffic to an Amazon CloudFront Web Distribution by Using Your Domain Name - Amazon Route 53](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-cloudfront-distribution.html):

> If you want to use your own domain name, use Amazon Route 53 to create an [alias record](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-choosing-alias-non-alias.html) that points to your CloudFront distribution. An alias record is a Route 53 extension to DNS. It's similar to a CNAME record, but you can create an alias record both for the root domain, such as `example.com`, and for subdomains, such as `www.example.com`. (You can create CNAME records only for subdomains.) When Route 53 receives a DNS query that matches the name and type of an alias record, Route 53 responds with the domain name that is associated with your distribution.

The steps are:

- Use an `A` Record in Amazon Route 53
- Set `Alias = Yes`
- Set the **Alias Target** to the CloudFront distribution

Please note that additional steps are required if you wish to use HTTPS (SSL) for the distribution. Using SNI is free, but dedicated IP addresses are expensive. See: [Custom SSL | Content Delivery Network (CDN), Domain Registration | Amazon CloudFront](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/custom-ssl-domains/)

Comment: To be clear: you can still register your domain name elsewhere. You only have to make an *alias* in Route 53 and point the registrar for your domain to the AWS nameservers.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately that is not possible.  This is a DNS limitation because
CNAME does not allow you to have the same record more than once in the zone, regardless of record type.  Therefore, the SOA and NS records would conflict with it, as well as MX record if present.

Comment: - You can use a rewrite filter that would take your request and replace the host portion with your desired.  .htaccess is available on both windows and linux hosts.
I wouldn't go this route because your server would be taking the hit as opposed to the CDN and therefore defeat the purpose.  Best option would be to move the zone to route53 and alias the A @ record.

Comment: could you expand on how this would work? Where would the rewrite filter live?